# How to add `action` to component element in EmberJs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am wrapping my component with `li` element. that's fine. But I am trying to add the action to `wrapped` element too.. But getting error. what is the correct way to add `action` to wrapped element?

any one help me?

my component:

```
<ul>
        {{#each cardList as |card index |}}
                {{
                    cs2i-cardcomponent 
                    card=card
                    index=index
                    enableNext='enableNext'
                    tagName="li"
                    {{action "selectCard card index"  }}//not works. trying to pass card and index to selected card in actions object in componet.js.
                }}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

my component js :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName:"",
    firstBalanceType : '',
    firstBalanceAmount : '',
    lastBalanceType : '',
    lastBalanceAmount : '',
    isSelected : false,


    actions : {
        selectCard : function(card,index) {
            this.set('selectedIndex', index );
            this.toggleProperty('isSelected');
            this.sendAction('enableNext', card);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Its `{{action "selectCard" card index  }}`

Comment: Still not works.. can't I pass the values to actions?

Comment: @Lux - the brase looks different color than syntex. getting error as `Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING
', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'OPEN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are sending `selectCard` closure action which wraps `selectCard` functions which is defined in current context.

```
{{cs2i-cardcomponent card=card index=index enableNext='enableNext' tagName="li" selectCard=(action "selectCard" card index)}}
```

Instead of the above I will encourage you to send the required data as params to component, from there you can send to data in arguments.

Follow [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/)

Comment: getting error as `ember.debug.js:18008 Error: Assertion Failed: An action named 'selectCard' was not found in <rdc-ui-servicerequest-csd@component:cs2i-cardlistcomponent::ember610>`

Comment: I have added my componet js for your reference.

Comment: try `selectCard=(action "selectCard" card index)`

Comment: So you are including `cs2i-cardcomponent` component in the `cs2i-cardlistcomponent` component. you need to define `selectCard` function in  `cs2i-cardlistcomponent` and pass it like this `selectCard=(action "selectCard" card index)`

Comment: it works for me, `action="selectCard"` but how to pass params?

Comment: Finally it works for me : `action=(action 'selectCard' card index )` very thanks to you!! for spending your golden time with me!!!